# Regular Expression : bash 3 vs bash 4

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, bash4

The follow code with a regular expression check does not outputs the same result between bash 3 and bash 4:

```
TESTCASE="testcase0"
[[ ${TESTCASE} =~ "^testcase[0-9\.]*$" ]]
echo $?
echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
```

bash 3.2 outputs a successful regular expression check:

```
0
testcase0
```

bash 4.1 fails the regular expression check:

```
1
<empty line>
```

I can't identify where in my regex pattern the expressions fails. I would need a code compatible between both version of bash.

Does anyone have a clue on what's my problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: `3.2` on mine outputs 1 with a blank line... Regardless you are not supposed to quote the regular expression.

Comment: I'm on a redhat machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In older versions of Bash (3.1), it was possible to use quotes around a regular expression in a test. In newer versions, the quotes are treated as part of the pattern, so the match fails.

The solution is to remove the quotes.

---

The recommended way to use regular expressions is this:

```
re='^testcase[0-9\.]*$'  # single quotes around variable
[[ ${TESTCASE} =~ $re ]] # unquoted variable used in test
```

This syntax should work in all versions of bash that support regular expressions. The variable isn't strictly necessary but it improves readability. See the [regular expressions section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1) of Greg's wiki for more details.

Regarding the use of a variable (from the link above):

> For cross-compatibility (to avoid having to escape parentheses, pipes and so on) use a variable to store your regex, e.g. `re='^\*( >| *Applying |.*\.diff|.*\.patch)'; [[ $var =~ $re ]]` This is much easier to maintain since you only write ERE syntax and avoid the need for shell-escaping, as well as being compatible with all 3.x BASH versions.

By the way, there's no need to escape the `.` inside the bracket expression.